# The "UMNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules ? React native android

Tags: android, react-native

The "UMNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that @unimodules/react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this block of code in MainApplication.java file

```
List<ReactPackage> unimodules = Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
      packages.addAll(unimodules);
     return packages;
```

Add this code in the current block of ReactPackage code, or you can replace this complete block of code

```
  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
     // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for 
example:
     // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
  List<ReactPackage> unimodules = Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
      packages.addAll(unimodules);
     return packages;
}
```